# Why there are two circles with similar colors that are not listed on legend?

Tags: python, altair

Why is this happening?

I am studying [a gallery example](https://traffic-viz.github.io/gallery/landing_configuration.html) of the Traffic library and I have encountered a weird thing on the figure the code generates. If you watch closely the circles on Oct 19 and Oct 20 at 06:00 and 08:00 you see this:

[image]

And it is very extrange that this two circles have a dark green circle inside them.

My theory is that the lighter green circle is sitting over the dark green circle, but this dark green color is not listed on the legend.
Here I leave the code that generates that figure.

```
from traffic.data.datasets import landing_zurich_2019
import altair as alt

stats = (
    landing_zurich_2019.all("aligned_on_LSZH")
    .eval(desc="", max_workers=8)
    .rename(columns=dict(flight_id="old_flight_id"))
    .summary(["old_flight_id_max", "stop", "ILS_max"])
    .query("stop.dt.month == 10")
    .rename(columns=dict(ILS_max="ILS", old_flight_id_max="flight_id"))
    .sort_values("stop")
)

data = (
    stats.assign(hour=lambda df: df.stop.dt.round("1H"))
    .groupby(["ILS", "hour"])
    .agg(dict(stop="count"))
    .rename(columns=dict(stop="count"))
    .reset_index()
)

selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=["ILS"], bind="legend")

alt.Chart(data).encode(
    alt.X("utchours(hour):O", title="hour of day (UTC)",),
    alt.Y("utcmonthdate(hour):O", title=""),
    color="ILS",
    size="count",
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(0.9), alt.value(0.2)),
).mark_circle().add_selection(selection)
```

Comment: Please do some debugging and include the relevant code here. We expect questions to be self-contained and not depend on external links for completeness to guard against [link-rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot). [Ask] | https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7523/174780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right that this is happening because you are plotting two circles on top of each other. It can be seen more clearly at Oct 26, 11:00 in the example you linked with the red and blue circles. If you want to make it clearer what is happening you can use `mark_point` to plot hollow circles instead.